# Snapshot Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some errors on my code and i don't know how to solve.

```
List<PostModel>_postListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){

  return snapshot.docs.map((doc){

    return PostModel(
     id: doc.id,
     text: doc.data()?['text']  ?? '',
     creator: doc.data()?['creator'] ?? '',
     timestamp: doc.data()?['timestamp'] ?? 0,
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

> Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`QuerySnapshot`](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query_snapshot.dart#L9) has the following declaration:

```
abstract class QuerySnapshot<T extends Object?> {
```

Which means to be able to use `map()` later on, you need to specify a type for `QuerySnapshot`, therefore do the following:

```
List_postListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot){
return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
  return PostModel(
   id: doc.id,
   text: doc.data()?['text']  ?? '',
   creator: doc.data()?['creator'] ?? '',
   timestamp: doc.data()?['timestamp'] ?? 0,
  );
}).toList();
```